# how to download a file from server, using asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to download a file from the server, I am getting access denied error, the path is different from what I am giving as input,   how can I pass the correct path

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string FileLoc = @"~/Upload/1984_Apple_Macintosh_Commercial.mp4";
    DownloadData(FileLoc);
}

public void DownloadData(string address)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, address);
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.DownloadFile(path, "1984_Apple_Macintosh_Commercial.mp4");
    }  
}
```

> Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\DevServer\10.0\1984_Apple_Macintosh_Commercial.mp4' is denied.

Updated Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        string FileLoc = @"c:\Files\1984_Apple_Macintosh_Commercial.mp4";
        DownloadData(FileLoc);
    }
}
public void DownloadData(string address)
{
    var path = Path.Combine(Request.PhysicalApplicationPath, address);
    WebClient Client = new WebClient();
    Client.DownloadFile(path, @"c:\Files\1984_Apple_Macintosh_Commercial.mp4");
}
```

Comment: Tilde expansion isn't a language feature. You need to change that to your actual home directory.

Comment: @Chris Not true, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.virtualpathutility.combine.aspx, 
Specifically: `The Combine method uses the AppDomainAppVirtualPath property value rather than the base path, if the relative path starts with a tilde and a slash mark (~/); otherwise, the Combine method uses the base path.`

Comment: I stand corrected, thank you @sinni800.

Comment: It makes no sense that you want to download something from the sameweb application that serves the request... Can't you copy the file or something?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter in `client.DownloadFile()` suggests that the file is actually placed inside the folder specified in the error. I suppose you are using Windows 7 and the Development Environment (Visual Studio?) is not started with admin rights, so you can't save in that folder.

As the second parameter, please change the path to an absolute path on your HDD which you don't need admin rights to have access to.

Example:

`client.DownloadFile(path, "c:\files\1984_Apple_Macintosh_Commercial.mp4")` implying that `c:\files` exists.

Comment: The process cannot access the file 'C:Upload\1984_Apple_Macintosh_Commercial.mp4' because it is being used by another process. Error

Comment: @Mark You have to make sure you only execute the page once. If it is being executed twice the error happens. What do you want to do with the file? Maybe a Path.GetTempFileName (Not sure if this is the correct name!) would be better?

Comment: As I said in the main post comment, what are you trying to achieve? You download a file from your OWN site to a folder on the hdd. Can't you copy the file or anything? Also, try it with a Path.GetTempFileName

Comment: You're specifying the same filename for both parameters. That's why it's in use. you're downloading it as you you're trying to overwrite it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have something confused here. `WebClient` is used to download a file from a server. You seem to be using it in your server-side code to 'download' a file from the same server; that doesn't make sense.

If you want to write code to send a file from your website to the client (browser), there are different ways to achieve this, e.g. the [Response.TransmitFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method (cf [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1185493.aspx/1) for a sample)